# Seekbar not working in native mediaplayer on Android 3.0 for m3u8 media

Tags: media-player, android-3.0-honeycomb

I am using the native media player for a video app on Android 3.x - which supports HTTP live streams (i.e. m3u8).

The video plays fine and I am able to pause and restart - but I cannot get the seekbar to work  - so I can move the thumb forward or backward and start playing from there.

This feature works great for mp4 media - just not for m3u8.

I see other players available on Android Market (e.g. Rock Player or Vitamio) that provide a seekbar that works great with m3u8 media - so I know it can be done.

My preference would be to use the native player, if possible.

Is there some setup or step I am missing?

Thanks in advance!

Srini